# HIbernate - @Where equivalent in XML configuration for Restricting Collections

Tags: hibernate

I would like to use the functionality that is provided by @Where to restrict collections only to the items that have status ACTIVE.
However, I cannot use annotations only xml. Therefore I look for @Where equivalent in xml but I cannot found anything.

Example ( I need something like  element "where")

```
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Teacher" table="teacher" >
    ...

    <bag name="subjects" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
        <key>
            <column name="id_policy" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="Subject" />
        <where>status = 'a'</where>
    </bag>

    ....
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Of course, I can use the custom collection loader, but this is quite ugly for such simple task.
The filter is a more suitable option but it must be enabled explicitly for Hibernate session and I simply need this "where" clause to be applied always.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

The [hibernate mapping DTD](http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd) mentions an optional `where` attribute on the class element and on all the collection elements (set, bag, etc.). It's not documented in the DTD, but given what is written [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html#objectstate-filters) regarding this "where" attribute, I'm pretty sure it's what you're looking for.

Comment: That's exactly what I need. Thank you very much for "super-quick" and relevant response :).

Answer (score 1):

you can easily add the where clause in the tag, like this example:

```
<bag name="subjects" inverse="true" cascade="save-update" where="flag_visible='S'" >
```