# Hibernate Adding where clause on one-to-many mapping

Tags: java, database, hibernate, mapping

I have this set on my .hbm file.

```
<set name="subTopicsTb" table="subtopics_tb" inverse="true" lazy="false" fetch="select">
        <key>
            <column name="topic_id" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="com.topics.model.SubTopics" />
    </set>
```

now, the default is that, hibernate get's all subtopics where the topic_id is the id.
i want to filter the subtopics. adding something like where subTopics.date is not null thanks

Answer (score 4):

This actually works, being `date` the column name in your DB. `where` attribute in the `set` **appends raw sql** to your query, so you have to specify as it is in your database and **NOT HQL**:

```xml
<set name="subTopicsTb" table="subtopics_tb" inverse="true" lazy="false" 
    fetch="select" where="date is not null">
    <key>
        <column name="topic_id" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="com.topics.model.SubTopics" />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a where clause? I don't know how you set that in an XML config .. but you can check out the annotation version [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection).

I found something at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907076/hibernate-where-equivalent-in-xml-configuration-for-restricting-collections) on how to add the where to your XML.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html) to retrieve your SubTopics? If so, you can include the filter in your selection. For example:

```
String query = "FROM SubTopic subtopic WHERE subtopic.date != null"
```